# How to reference the innerText of a Button Element which has lots of spaces and remove any leading/trailing/extra spaces in the String using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom

```
<button class="no-style no-border no-margin no-padding no-bg hover-link" style="font-weight: inherit; 
          text-align: left;" onclick="Company.hideSchedule('Sales', 'profit-loss', this)" data-child- 
          count="1">Sales&nbsp;
    <span class="blue-500">-
    </span>**strong text**
</button>
```

After the innerText is referenced, I want to remove all the leading/trailing/extra spaces in between the string to use it in a vba function, like so

```
If (Trim(button.innerText) = "Sales") Then
```

Link to the html code is under Profit & Loss Table > Sales (1st row):

https://www.screener.in/company/DIVISLAB/consolidated/

Comment: Don't. Use Instr instead.  If Instr(button.innertterxt,"Sales")>0 then

Comment: @freeflow - Instr, Already tried .... Is there a way to remove the leading/trailing/extra spaces from the innerText of the 'button element' ?

Comment: Why doesn't Instr do the job?

Comment: The function, If Instr(button.innerText, "Sales") > 0 gave me :
"Sales -"  = (It did not remove extra space between 'Sales' and '-'. 

I just need the substring, "Sales". Whitespace " " and "-" must be removed.

Comment: `Instr` doesn't give you "Sales -" and the space before the "-" is **not** an extra space. A space is considered extra if it comes after another space. If you want to remove leading/trailing/extra spaces, then use `Trim`. If you want to remove other chars, use `Replace`. If you simply want to test if the inner text has "Sales", use either `Instr(1, button.innerText, "Sales") > 0` or `button.innerText Like "*Sales*"`. For case insensitive comparison, user either `Instr(1, button.innerText, "Sales", vbTextCompare) > 0` or `button.innerText Like "*[Ss]ales*"`.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry - Sorry, It gave me "Sales -  ". Anyway, I just want to extract the substring "Sales" from the above result and also remove the special character  '-'

Comment: @Super Symmetry - I used Mid(Trim(button.innerText), 1, 5) -> 'Sales' . Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @freeflow - Thanks for the InStr